# LogBack - Setting Logging Pattern with App Info

Tags: android, logging, logback

I have been learning how to use LogBack Android and I was wondering how do you set the pattern so it always includes certain information without having to pass it in `log.error`, `log.info`.

I know setting a pattern is done:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread][%logger{0}] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

How would I include other information such as UserId (The user that is logged into my application) or DeviceId or other information that is specific to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [LOGBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) you will accomplish it [writing your own custom Layout](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html).

The [FAQ from Tony19](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki/FAQ) states some differences between `logback` and `logback-android` but I've searched the `logback-android` java-doc and the solution-key class `LayoutBase<E>` can be found. I guess it will work.

Hope it helps!